# python lambda function of 0 arity

Tags: python, function, lambda

is it possible to write the following using Python's lambda notation?

`def no(): return`

the closest i can without a sytax error is

`no = lambda _: no`

which has the following property:

```
>>> no
<function <lambda> at 0x101e69f80>
>>> no(4)
<function <lambda> at 0x101e69f80>
>>> no(no(4))
<function <lambda> at 0x101e69f80>

>>> no == no(no)
True
>>> no == no(4)
True
no == no(no(4))
True
>>> no == 4
no == 4
False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def no1():return
...
>>> no = lambda : None
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(no)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(no1)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your explicit version returns `None`. Since lambda functions consist only of an expression, the equivalent code is therefore

```
no = lambda: None
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of

```
def no():
    return
```

is

```
no = lambda: None
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for this:

```
lambda: None
```

It's equivalent because a function with an empty `return`, or which exits simply by exhausting the function text, returns `None`.